# how to calculate compound annual growth rate using hive sql or hiveql

Tags: hive

I need help in calculating compound annual growth rate in hive. it looks like the operator i need is ^ but it has different meaning looks like.
my table 
zipcode, agerange year gender
55901    0-12     2010   m
55901    13-16    2010   f

and the data is for year 2010 and 2016 only. i have calculated it in tableau but would prefer the calculation using sql/hiveql.

thank you in advance
st

Comment: Kindly add what you have done and where you are struck .

Comment: i have used a formula in tableau and did not do any in sql